# Fetch emails using context io api

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth-2.0, contextio

I am using context io api for fetching mails from gmail accounts.I want do the gmail authentication seperately.That means not use the connect_token .

```
Steps
Step 1 : Gmail authentication (using oauth2)
Step 2: Add account to context io
Step 3: Fetch emails
```

I am using the PHP files downloaded by the GitHub .

I am using the below code for Add New account to Context io

```
$para=array('email'=>$_SESSION['google_data']['email'],'first_name'=>$_SESSION['google_data']['given_name'],'last_name'=>$_SESSION['google_data']['family_name'],'username'=>$_SESSION['google_data']['email'],'provider_consumer_key'=>'ffddfdfdf','provider_refresh_token'=>$refresh_token,'type'=>'IMAP','server'=>'imap.googlemail.com','port'=>993);

$r =$contextIO->addAccount($para);
```

The account is created but it is not active ,ie, the account has no mail boxes.So I can't fetch the emails.

Is this a correct method?Anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct, assuming that the parameters you're pulling from `$_SESSION` are the correct information for the account. You also need to register your oauth key to [oauth_providers](http://context.io/docs/2.0/oauth_providers) in the API.

You can check the response from the `addAccount` call to see if there are any issues.

(Full disclosure: I work on the Context.IO team)